# AngularJS MVC Create Model Object from Factory Service Response and then Update the Data on the View

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, service, model, factory

I have a view where the user enters data and submits the data to the server. The same view has an ng-table that gets updated with the server response data.

What I am trying to do is create a View, the View pulls the data from the Controller. The Controller pulls the data from a Model. The Model is populated by a Factory response.

Does anyone have a basic example of this? I cannot find any examples of where a Model is used. I want other controllers in my UI to use this same model, to share data.

The biggest issues that I cannot figure out is how to share data between multiple controllers. When the data is updated, I want each controller to get the updated data, hence the need for a Model.

I am calling a Web Service to get my data.

Any code examples would be helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would expect what you want is something like this.

In html.

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    ctrlA
    <div ng-controller="ctrlA">
        <input ng-model="mymodel.name">
    </div>

    ctrlB
    <div ng-controller="ctrlB">
        <input ng-model="mymodel.name">
    </div>
</div>
```

In js. (In this sample I built the model with static value to clear the  essence. However you could also get some data from server to build the model.)

```
angular.module('myapp',[]).service('myservice', function(){
    this.sharemodel = {
        name: undefined
    }
})

function ctrlA($scope, myservice){
    $scope.mymodel = myservice.sharemodel;
}

function ctrlB($scope, myservice){
    $scope.mymodel = myservice.sharemodel;
}
```

I setup [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/gdm59xrp/).

Comment: The issue I see is if you update the data in ctrlA, it doesn't reflect in ctrlB. I haven't been able to get around this. Any ideas?

Comment: When you change input value in ctrlA, it **does** reflect in ctrlB. This means that updating the data in ctrlA reflect the data in ctrlB, because the data reffers to same model object.
If you want to change more clearly in ctrlA, please see this updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/gdm59xrp/1/).

Comment: I am trying to update the model via a service call, not through user input. Then, let the View display the updated results. For example, you have a ng-table. You also have a button to get data. User clicks the button and makes a service call. I want to Factory service call response to update the model. When the model is updated, I want the ng-table to load the new data. I want that data to be used via any controller in the App. I should have been more clear. Any example of that? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I might have gradually understand what you want. If the point is to update the model via a service call, [this sample](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/gdm59xrp/3/) could be what you imagined.